# How did Letac solve $x_1^k + x_2^k + \dots +x_9^k = 0$ for $k = 1, 3, 5, 7$ in 1942?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

It's quite easy to find integer solutions to,

$$x_0^k + x_1^k + \dots +x_9^k = 0$$

for $k = 1, 3, 5, 7$. One I found is, if $x^2-10y^2 = 9$, then,

$$1 + 5^k + (3+2y)^k + (3-2y)^k + (-3+3y)^k + (-3-3y)^k = (-2+x)^k + (-2-x)^k + (5-y)^k + (5+y)^k$$

However, Letac found in 1942 two special cases with $x_0 = 0$ (the case $x_0 = x_1 = 0$ is impossible), namely,

$$\{\,0, 34, 58, 82, 98\,\} = \{\,13, 16, 69, 75, 99\,\}$$

$$\{\,0, 63, 119, 161, 169\,\} = \{\,8, 50, 132, 148, 174\,\}$$

How did he do it?

The reference is *A. Letac, Gazeta Matematica, 48 (1942), p. 68-69*, and I'm hoping someone with JSTOR can explicitly give the answer.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation8thPowers.html

Comment: http://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/d/d231.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite familiar with Mathworld, having contributed several entries myself (see [Piezas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/Piezas.html)) but how Letac found that special multigrade is not there.

Comment: Do you have access to Gloden's book on multigrade equations? Maybe he gives some ideas about Letac's methods.

Comment: You mean Gloden's _Mehrgradige Gleichungen_, 1944? Unfortunately, no. :-( Maybe someone in this forum has though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the two solutions you mention, only the second appears in Letac’s note.

He used (among other things) the following two lemmas :

**Fact 1.**  If $a_1^k+a_2^k+a_3^k=b_1^k+b_2^k+b_3^k$ for
$k=2$ and $k=4$, then 
$$
a_1^p+(\pm a_2)^p+(\pm a_3)^p+(2b_1)^p+(2b_2)^p+(2b_3)^p=
b_1^p+(\pm b_2)^p+(\pm b_3)^p+(2a_1)^p+(2a_2)^p+(2a_3)^p \ (p=2,4,6,8)
$$

**Fact 2.**  Under the hypotheses of fact 1, for $h=\frac{a_1+a_2-a_3}{4}$
we have

$$
(2a_1-3h)^k+(2a_2-h)^k+(2a_2-3h)^k+(2a_2-h)^k+(2b_3+h)^k=
(2a_3+h)^k+(2a_3+h)^k+(2b_1-h)^k+(2b_1-h)^k+(2b_2-h)^k+(3h)^k \ (k=1,3,5)
$$

Comment: Fact 1 does not seem to be correct. e.g. for @TitoPiezas's example $(a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3)=(195,71,98,21,190,127)$ it doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

There are some significant typos in Delanoy's answer, but I'll accept it nonetheless as it pointed me in the right direction. (Sorry for the delay.)

Let $a^k+b^k+c^k = d^k+e^k+f^k,\;\; k =2,4\tag{1}$

*Theorem 1* (Birck-Sinha): "Fact 1" should be instead, given (1) then,

\begin{aligned}&(a+b+c)^k + (-a+b+c)^k + (a-b+c)^k + (a+b-c)^k + (2d)^k + (2e)^k + (2f)^k =\\
&(2a)^k + (2b)^k + (2c)^k  + (-d+e+f)^k +  (d-e+f)^k + (d+e-f)^k + (d+e+f)^k\end{aligned}

for $k = 2,4,6,8$.

*Theorem 2* (Gloden-Sinha): "Fact 2" should be, let (1) have the constraint $a+b-c = 2(d+e-f)$, then,

\begin{aligned}&(2a-3h)^k + (2a-h)^k + (2b-3h)^k + (2b-h)^k + (2f+h)^k =\\ &(2c+h)^k + (2c+3h)^k + (2d-h)^k + (2e-h)^k + (3h)^k\end{aligned}

where $h = (d+e-f)/2$ for $k = 1,3,5,7$.

We can now reverse-engineer Letac's solution and find that he started with,

$$195^k+71^k+98^k = 21^k+190^k+127^k,\;\; k = 2,4\tag{2}$$

and using Theorem 2,

$$132^k+174^k+8^k+50^k+148^k = 119^k+161^k+0^k+169^k+63^k,\;\; k = 1,3,5,7$$

after removing a common factor. Thus, he gave (1) the second constraint $2d-h = 3d-e+f = 0$, though how he found (2) is a question in itself.

Unfortunately, it can be shown these two constraints reduce (1) to the problem of making two quartic polynomials (in one variable) into a square, hence there are only a finite number of rational solutions, and I wasn't able to find additional ones.

P.S. I'm still checking if Letac's first solution also uses *Theorem 2*.

Comment: I've now checked Letac's first solution {$0,34,58,82,98$}={$13,16,69,75,99$} and verified it does not use _Theorem 2_. (There are no $a,b,c,d,e,f$ which yields those values.) He must have employed another approach.